# In an ASP.MVC app, how to define a View and bring it in from an assembly?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am writing an ASP.MVC application that behaves as a host of future plug-ins that are yet to be written.  These plugins will be packaged as DLL in separate assemblies.  One of the things that a plugin is responsible for is to provide its own View.  Preferable that the main app will not have to be recompiled, each time a new plugin is written.  What is the best way to have the main app looking for views that are in other assemblies?

UPDATE: My last resort is to to leverage the Post-Build events to copy View files to the View folder of the main app.  But I am looking for a better way.

Comment: Cool question!  Will you also support partial views?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [mvcms project](http://cmsmvc.codeplex.com/) which does exactly what you are trying to do.